# Why Python returns 1 for "True and 1" expression? or False for "False and 1"?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie at learning programming, I'm self teaching so I would greatly appreciate your answers. :)

```
>>> True and 1
1

>>> False and 1
False
```

Comment: Because 1 is truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False is a "falsy"  value and True is a "truthy" value.  Truthy is having a value that has "Truth" (truth-like).  Falsy is a value that has falseness (false-like). Furthermore, 1 is a truthy value and 0 is falsy.  Translating your expressions leaves us "Truthy and Truthy", "Fasly and Truthy".

Based on basic boolean logic, `Truthy and Truthy` is `True`.  `Truthy and Falsy` is `False`.  Lastly, all of the following are equal based on the previous paragraph:

```
1 and True, True and True
False or 1, False or True
0 and 0, False and False
1 and 0, True and False
```

Comment: Why does `True and 1` evaluate as `1`?

Comment: Truthy and Truthy is Truthy (1 == Truthy)

Comment: You don't explain what truthy and falsey mean. `False` is not falsey. `False` is `False`.

Comment: @PeterWood: Please review my edit, and if it is satisfactory, change your vote.  If it isn't satisfactory, lmk because I appreciate the constructive feedback.

Comment: Why does `1 and True` evaluate as `True` but `True and 1` evaluate as `1`?

Comment: Is that really what OP is asking? Doesn't really seem that way to me @PeterWood

Comment: it's unclear what the OP is asking and I have voted to close the question.

Comment: I agree.  But if you don't completely understand what the OP is asking, why would you downvote a post because it doesn't cover what the op is asking? @PeterWood

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99076/discussion-between-intboolstring-and-peter-wood).